# Mix and match spatial-reference systems?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, geospatial

Assuming that I have a table of postal codes, with a `Geography` column that was populated with Global - WGS84 (SRID 4326), can I accurately compare them (using `STDistance`) with a `Geography` point that has been populated with North America – NAD83 (SRID 4269)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, No.

SQL Server requires for spatial functions that  all items' have the same SRID.  This is because the SRID provides other information in the background used to calculate distances and such on an ellipsoidal model.

That said, you could have a second column which is calculated to have a common SRID and use that for distance calculations.  It's as simple as:

```
Declare @commonSrid geography = geography::STGeomFromWKB(<existing column>.STAsBinary(), 4326);
```

In doing this, you must be sure that all SRIDs are based from latitude and longitude decimal coordinates, and not for example grid references.  Also because you're not doing a proper conversion between them, you may find distances are not 100% accurate - but they will be very very close.

Comment: I've found a number of articles that suggest that the two datum don't differ by much, for example: [Difference Between WGS84 and NAD83](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-wgs84-and-nad83/).  Assuming that this is true, and that I want to compare distances on orders of magnitude of Km, could I just compare the heterogeneous values without fear of introducing significant errors?  Assumedly, I'd want to specify the correct source of the datum when the `Geography` field is populated, however (`Geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(<LONGITUDE> <LATITUDE>)', 4269)`).

Comment: @craig I would certainly assume there will be no significant error.  The ellipsoid difference is so small it won't affect anything.  I'm unsure of the effect that the movement of the prime meridian would have (if any), but again it was 100m so I wouldn't worry too much about it (unless you're trying to position someone in a building)!

Comment: @craig If you want to keep the SRID then yes, populate your Geography field with SRID 4269.  However, you will then have to have a Geography4326 field that contains the equivalent but for WGS84 if you want to use any Spatial Functions - you don't want the overhead of "re-projecting" it for every query, but it's easy to absorb the overhead on insert / update.  Make sense?

Comment: Do both systems use the same coordinate system (latitude=equator;longitude=[IERS Reference Meridian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IERS_Reference_Meridian))?  The answer would seem to be yes, but I can't seem to find the canonical reference.

Comment: So, one field for 4269 and one field for 4326?  The hard part is knowing when to reference one or the other.  What are the issues with a single field populated with heterogeneous values (i.e. some rows 4269, some rows 4326)?

Comment: Yes they do.  See [This useful website](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/) for WGS84 and you can find the NAD83 on there too.  If you download and compare the .prj files in Notepad, you'll see they're virtually identical.  Bounds seems to be the only significant difference - naturally!

Comment: Yes, two fields if you want to preserve their SRIDS.  If you store both in a single column, you won't be able to use any functions that compare (such as STDistance()) as all Spatial Functions in SQL require that all geographies used in the query have the same SRID.  Alternatively, if you wish, store one Geography column and have a second INT field to store the original SRID value?